# Add listener to view inside an listview

Tags: android, listview

I have a listview with `EditText` views. I want to add an setOnFocusChangeListener to each edit text. However, I don't know how to access the position of that view

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list, null);
            holder.editText = (EditText)convertView.findViewById(R.id.attribute_value);
            try {
                convertView.setTag(holder);
            } catch (NullPointerException e) {
                throw new NullPointerException("ViewHolder is empty.");
            }
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
        }

        holder.editText.setText("my text");
        holder.editText.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
                updateValue(position);
            }
        });


        return convertView;
    }
```

Unfortunately, I can't pass the `position` variable. When I make a `final` variable, it somehow breaks up the other views in the list.

Comment: `catch (NullPointerException` and `throw new NullPointerException` ... really? That would say `convertView` is null, not the holder is empty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I don't know how to access the position of that view

Use `setTag/getTag` method of `EditText` for accessing `position` in `onFocusChange` method with-out making `position` `final`:

```
holder.editText.setText("my text");
holder.editText.setTag(position);
```

and in `onFocusChange` use `v` first parameter to send value:

```
public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
    updateValue(Integer.parseInt(v.getTag().toString()));
 }
```

Comment: That looks very promising, I'll try that

Answer (score 0):

You have a few options, but I'll go over two:

You should be able to do this:

```
final int itemPosition = position;
holder.editText.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
            updateValue(itemPosition);
        }
    });
```

Or you can go the tag route:

```
holder.editText.setText("my text");
holder.editText.setTag(position);
```